# Javascript - Code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create new web page as like http://drag-2-share.appspot.com. I copied the  source code and test in local to understand more on how the they developed it, but when I saved to my local it didn't work as per the webpage. As I know it should save into the list. I never did javascript before so appreciate if someone can assist me. Below is the code, you can save in local and test it.

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Drag2Share</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="drop_zone">
    <select id="fileSelect"></select>
    <button onclick="handleView();">View</button>
    <button onclick="handleDownload();">Download</button>
    <button onclick="updateSelector();">Update</button>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="drop_text">Drop File(s) Here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object
        var finished;
        for ( var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', '/files/' + file.name);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (!files[i + 1] && !finished) {
                    window.alert("Upload Completed");
                    finished = true;
                    updateSelector();
                }
            }
            request.send(file);
        }
        document.getElementById('drop_zone').className = "";
    }

    function handleDragOver(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('drop_zone').className = "over";
    }

    function handleLeave(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('drop_zone').className = "";
    }

    function handleView() {
        var select = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
        window.open("files/" + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
    }

    function handleDownload() {
        var select = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
        window.location += "files/"
                + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value + "?download";
    }

    function updateSelector() {
        var select = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
        while (select.options.length > 0) {
            select.remove(0);
        }
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', '/info', false);
        request.send(null);
        var json = eval(request.responseText);
        for ( var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
            AddSelectOption(select, json[i], json[i], true);
        select.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    function AddSelectOption(selectObj, text, value, isSelected) {
        if (selectObj != null && selectObj.options != null)
            selectObj.options[selectObj.options.length] = new Option(text,
                    value, false, isSelected);
    }

    // Setup the dnd listeners.
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleLeave, false);
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);

    // Initialize file selector
    updateSelector();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#drop_zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#drop_zone.over {
  background: gray;
}

#drop_text {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

html,body,table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define "didn't work" in more detail.

Comment: If you never did Javascript before, might I suggest starting on some simpler scripts and work your way up from there? Blindly copying other people's code and then coming here to ask why it doesn't work is not the way to go.

Comment: when I dragged in the file...the pop up works but i dont know where the file went.

Comment: @Mr Lister Thanks for the advice, I'm actually reading the javascript tutorial. The reason i post here because, the issue might be hard for me but it just a piece of cake for experts. I just hoping experts can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will not work completely (especially upload file code) unless you also write the server side code associated with that page. Nothing's wrong with the JavaScript (after all you copied it from a working site). Its just that the server side code that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikhil has said the Server side code is missing,

i would maybe start looking here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp